# How to remove an item from the action bar drop down navigation menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an app with an action bar that has drop down navigation ( like a spinner ). Is it possible to programmatically remove an item from the list?

EDIT: Relevant code:

```
// Set up the dropdown list navigation in the action bar.
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(
        // Specify a SpinnerAdapter to populate the dropdown list.
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBarThemedContextCompat(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        android.R.id.text1, list), this);
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: The question is self-explanatory, and the only relevant code is where I create a spinner adapter to populate the list, but I posted it anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. get ActionBar instance by calling  **getActionBar();**
2. remove the App Name in ActionBar by **setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);**
3. set Action bar Navigation as List 
   **actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);**
4. *Create a Arraylist  and add item you want to be in Spinner in Menu.*
5. bind the List to ArrayAdapter.
6. set the adapter to action Bar
7. now spinner in Action Bar is created.
8. to remove the item just remove the item in list and call **notifyDataSetChanged()** this in turn refresh the adapter and reflect on UI.

Here is Full Code to Remove the Item  in `(Spinner )` in action bar

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {

    ActionBar actionBar;
    List spinnerList;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

         spinnerList = new ArrayList();
        spinnerList.add("Item1");
        spinnerList.add("Item2");
        spinnerList.add("Item3");
        spinnerList.add("Item4");
         adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerList);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, this);
        removeItemInActionBar(2);

    }

    public void removeItemInActionBar(int position) {
        spinnerList.remove(position);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had tried updating the array with the items before, but I had not used notiftyDataSetChanged()

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); used in removeItemInActionBar(); It makes immediate changes in User View i.e Spinner for above Code